# Was there a time when some 1st person plurals ended with “-am”?

Tags: verbs, history, apocope

I was reading an old document put on the web and saw “siam” where I expected “siamo.”

I was about to report a typo when I realized that at least a third of the verbs were that way—“dobbiam” and “abbiam” per esempio.

Was that ever normal long long ago?

Comment: It is still normal, I do it all the time :-)

Comment: You mean 1st person plurals, don't you?

Comment: @randomatlabuser, I agree it's still normal, but if you really do it all the time I fear people may think you are a poet...

Comment: @DaG - Si, dispiace.

Comment: @Walter Tross, probably this is something Italians do all the time without really being aware of it. Consider the **polirematica** ([1](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/espressioni-polirematiche_(La_grammatica_italiana)/), [2](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/parole-polirematiche_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/)) "*un bel po'* ": three apocopic words for a very frequent phrase used every day by millions of people who are not poets and presumably ignore what an apocope is.

Comment: @randomatlabuser, agreed - I thought you were referring to _siam_, _dobbiam_ and _abbiam_.

Comment: "siam peccatori ma figli tuoi" :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is an apocope (in Italian *troncamento* or *apocope*), a usual phenomenon in which one or more final letters of a word are omitted, usually for metrical or general euphonic reasons, not specific of a particular grammatical person or number (but with its own empirical rules).

Some *troncamenti* are now fixed (think about *buon giorno* rather than **buono giorno*, *un uomo* rather than **uno uomo*, *dottor Rossi* vs.**dottore Rossi*). Others are optional, and left to one's sense of the language and the different emphasis to be given to a sentence (*ti vuole bene* as well as *ti vuol bene*).

In Italian you can read more about it in Treccani *Enciclopedia dell'Italiano*'s [article about *troncamento*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/troncamento_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/).

Comment: "un uomo" is not an apocope actually, as "un" does exist as article

Comment: Thanks for your remark, but the article is actually *uno*, which «ha al masch. sing. la variante apocopata *un*» (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/uno/).

Comment: Touché, I'm sorry.

Comment: let me expand on an example of yours: _ti vuole bene parlare di me_ vs _ti vuol ben parlar di me_

Comment: Thanks for the interesting info about *troncamento*.  I will have to read that article.  Turns out this time, though, it was just a lot of sloppy typing--I found another web page with the same text except no dropped 'o'

Comment: @MadHatter Many (all?) the primary school teacher believe that it's convenient to tell lies to children, so they explain that there are three indeterminate articles, namely *un*, *uno* and *una*. This may be a pedagogically sound lie: teaching sometimes *requires* telling white lies.

Comment: @egreg: Apart from temporarily protecting children from the most horrible aspects of human actions, I do not advocate lying to them. As you see, the linguistic white lies you admit have enduring, detrimental consequences (see also the “no accent on *sé stesso*” fable and so on).

Comment: @DaG I said *may*! Unfortunately, Italian grammar is often taken for granted in high school, so it's not discussed in greater depth when students have more maturity for understanding the real processes.

Comment: I do not consider it good pedagogy to tell a student something that they will later have to unlearn.  If the truth is too complicated to explain, then either the student isn't ready for it or the teacher doesn't understand it well.  When I was a teacher, correcting the damage done by erroneous simplifications was one of my more frustrating duties.